# Correlating n number of coordinate points

Tags: python, scipy, coordinates, scikit-learn, astronomy

I have a set of coordinates that I get from identifying some sources in an image and I have another set of coordinates from a text file catalog that correspond to the sources in the image. I wanted to correlate the coordinates in the textfile with the coordinate identified in the image. Although both coordinate frame is the same, they have slight differences due to systematics, so I could only rely on the relative relation between them (e.g. the distance between points). I could have any number of source in one image, but the number is not large, probably no more than 5. In the example below, the goal is to figure out what the point on the left figure corresponds to in the right picture by matching up a --> a', b--> b', and c--> c'.
[image]

Is there some Python package/ module that performs similar function? 
I am not too sure how this type of coordinate comparison with n-sources would be hard-coded in.

Comment: If the distortion is minor, my first idea would be to search for point `a'` in a circle around `a`, where the diameter is small and/or could be a parameter. Can't really say much else without knowing your data structures.

Comment: Maybe scikit.learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but this might be able to help. I have used this earlier for something similar. its called openCV.
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html